# String replacement in batch file

Tags: command-line, batch-file

We can replace strings in a batch file using the following command

```
set str="jump over the chair"
set str=%str:chair=table%
```

These lines work fine and change the string "jump over the chair" to "jump over the table". Now I want to replace the word "chair" in the string with some variable and I don't know how to do it.

```
set word=table
set str="jump over the chair"
??
```

Any ideas?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to replace string inside a bat file with command line parameter string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5816178/how-to-replace-string-inside-a-bat-file-with-command-line-parameter-string) which has much more informal answer (it has the same solutions as the answers here though)

Comment: now it's not important who was first, but it's good to link identical questions and point to the most irrefragable answer

Comment: https://cmdshell.blog/2022/02/08/string-replacement-in-a-batch-file/

Answer (score 105, accepted):

You can use the following little trick:

```
set word=table
set str="jump over the chair"
call set str=%%str:chair=%word%%%
echo %str%
```

The `call` there causes another layer of variable expansion, making it necessary to quote the original `%` signs but it all works out in the end.

Comment: I like this solution, escaping strings is always problematic in batch files, ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION just adds another character to worry about.

Comment: Important thing regarding answer provided by **Joey**. That you need to put the code into batch file for it to work.
If you just test it in command line, it will return unexpected `%"jump over the "word%%%`.
Just be aware, that code in batch files and in command line may produce different results.

Comment: Building on dadhi's spot-on comment, the solution for command line is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29944902/how-to-replace-with-percent-character-in-cmd-exe.

Comment: Upvoting this answer because it works both ways, with the environment variable in either position, or in both the "before" and "after" positions:  
`set word=table  `  `set str="jump over the chair"  `  
`call set str=%%str:chair=%word%%%  `  
`echo %str%  `  

`set word1=chair  `  
`set word2=desk  `  
`set str="jump over the chair"  `  
`call set str=%%str:%word1%=%word2%%%  `  
`echo %str%'  `

Comment: Can be really useful to convert a "local path" to an "admin share" path by prepending \\servername\ and then using this trick to just replace drive letter colon to a $.

Comment: trying to use this technique with both string_to_search_in and pattern_to_replace are given in variable `call set str=%%%string%:%pattern%=#%%` but it does not work for me.

Comment: "_making it necessary to **quote** the original % signs_" Where **quote** means **escape** I think? (Or I'm missing something.)

Answer (score 91):

You can use !, but you must have the ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION switch set.

```
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
set word=table
set str="jump over the chair"
set str=%str:chair=!word!%
```

Comment: But what if `str` itself is from delayed expansion? `set str=!str:chair=!word!!` does not work correctly.

Comment: I get `"jump over the !word!"`.

Comment: @ImaginaryHuman072889 I was able using a combo of this and the answer below, i.e., `call set str=%%str:chair=!word!%%`

Answer (score 1):

I was able to use Joey's Answer to create a function:

Use it as:

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

SET "MYTEXT=jump over the chair"
echo !MYTEXT!
call:ReplaceText "!MYTEXT!" chair table RESULT
echo !RESULT!

GOTO:EOF
```

And these Functions to the bottom of your Batch File.

```
:FUNCTIONS
@REM FUNCTIONS AREA
GOTO:EOF
EXIT /B

:ReplaceText
::Replace Text In String
::USE:
:: CALL:ReplaceText "!OrginalText!" OldWordToReplace NewWordToUse  Result
::Example
::SET "MYTEXT=jump over the chair"
::  echo !MYTEXT!
::  call:ReplaceText "!MYTEXT!" chair table RESULT
::  echo !RESULT!
::
:: Remember to use the "! on the input text, but NOT on the Output text.
:: The Following is Wrong: "!MYTEXT!" !chair! !table! !RESULT!
:: ^^Because it has a ! around the chair table and RESULT
:: Remember to add quotes "" around the MYTEXT Variable when calling.
:: If you don't add quotes, it won't treat it as a single string
::
set "OrginalText=%~1"
set "OldWord=%~2"
set "NewWord=%~3"
call set OrginalText=%%OrginalText:!OldWord!=!NewWord!%%
SET %4=!OrginalText!
GOTO:EOF
```

And remember you MUST add "SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION" to the top of your batch file or else none of this will work properly.

```
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
@REM # Remember to add this to the top of your batch file.
```

Answer (score -4):

This works fine

```
@echo off    
set word=table    
set str=jump over the chair    
set rpl=%str:chair=%%word%    
echo %rpl%
```

Comment: Sorry, it looks good, BUT it's wrong! It removes the word `chair` and append the word `table`, but it doesn't exchange the two words. Try to replace the word `over` with `under` and you get `jump  the chairunder`