# Batch-script for determining relative paths in a loop

Tags: shell, batch-file, command-line, windows-7

I want to implement a batch script in Windows 7 that iterates over all files in a folder and it cuts the folder prefix, e.g. Folder = "C:\A\B\" and the file = "C:\A\B\C\D.E" should output "C\D.E". My current code looks like this:

```
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET DIRECTORY=C:\DEV\SVN\QA\
for /R %DIRECTORY% %%f in (*.*) do (
REM GET RELATIVE PATH
echo File=%%f
echo Path=%TARGET_PATH_FOR_SOURCE%
set result=%f:!TARGET_PATH_FOR_SOURCE!=%

echo Result=!result!
)
```

I get the following result:

```
File=C:\DEV\SVN\QA\1.0\A\B\C.txt
Path=C:\DEV\SVN\QA\1.0
Result=C:\DEV\SVN\QA\1.0=    <<< Expected result: "A\B\C.txt"
```

I found this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2772456/string-replacement-in-batch-file) and tried this in the loop without success. Can you help me please?

Thank you!

Comment: Wrong language selected. German:Ist dir aufgefallen, dass dies ein englisch sprachiges Forum ist?

Comment: Ich habe hier schon einige Fragen gefunden, die in deutsch formuliert wurden.

Comment: This question is off-topic because it is not in English

Comment: I have translated it! I saw some questions in german. So I thought it is okay to write in german, sorry! It is my first post.

Comment: You're trying to do `SET` expansion with a `FOR` variable. That won't work. Use Set File=%%f and !File:!TARGET_PATH_FOR_SOURCE!=! instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work.

It's necessary to copy the FOR loop parameter to a variable, as the replace operations works only with variables.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
SET DIRECTORY==C:\DEV\SVN\QA
set TARGET_PATH_FOR_SOURCE==C:\DEV\SVN\QA\1.0
echo Path=%TARGET_PATH_FOR_SOURCE%
for /R %DIRECTORY% %%x in (*.*) do (
    REM GET RELATIVE PATH
    set "file=%%x"
    set result=!file:%TARGET_PATH_FOR_SOURCE%=!
    echo Result=!result!
)
```

Answer (score 2):

referring to answer of "jeb":
i had a headache for hours getting this to work. obviously it was easier than expected. this:

```
SET DIRECTORY==C:\DEV\SVN\QA
set TARGET_PATH_FOR_SOURCE==C:\DEV\SVN\QA\1.0
```

must be written without "==":

```
set DIRECTORY=C:\DEV\SVN\QA
set TARGET_PATH_FOR_SOURCE=C:\DEV\SVN\QA\1.0
```

EDIT:
Well, It turns out that I had to do even more. Additionally change this:

```
set result=!file:%TARGET_PATH_FOR_SOURCE%=!
```

to this, then it should be fine:

```
call set result=%%file:!TARGET_PATH_FOR_SOURCE!=%%
```