# Add a suffix to some lines of a text file with a batch

Tags: batch-file

The code I found allows me to add text to every line of a txt file, but I would like to edit only the lines that begin with HTTP

```
@echo off
setLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /f "tokens=* delims= " %%a in (input.txt) do (
set /a N+=1
echo ^%%a^|User-Agent=Vlc>>output.txt
)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Batch file if string starts by](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36228474/batch-file-if-string-starts-by)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace your `echo` line inside the for loop with the following:

```
set _line=%%a
set _suffix=
if "!_line:~0,4!"=="HTTP" set _suffix=^|User-Agent=Vlc
echo %%a!_suffix!>>output.txt
```

Comment: After writing HTTP in lowercase it works perfectly, I didn't think it was case sensitive, thanks!