# Replace Space in %USERNAME% With Underscore

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

Is there any way to replace a space in %username% with an underscore. Within cmd.

For example:

Username: john doe

Actual Folder path for %username%: john_doe

```
    NET USE Z: \\server\folder\%username%\ /P:Yes
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2772456/string-replacement-in-batch-file

Comment: State `NET USE Z: "\\server\folder\%username%" /PERSISTENT:Yes` instead, so you can use directory names with spaces in them...

Answer (score 3):

```
set "newusername=%username: =_%"
```

creates a new variable with the space replaced.