# Remove section of filename

Tags: filenames

I am needing a batch file to remove a certain part from multiple filenames in the same directory.

Example:
I have over 80,000+ files with the title like so:

```
Test Title, The - Conspiracy.zip
```

I am needing ", The" removed from file names leavin the titles like so:

```
Test Title - Conspiracy.zip
```

PS, I am needing this in Batch file only!

Any help is much appreciated!
THANX!!!

Answer (score 2):

I found what I needed to use and thank you all for the quick replies and help!

```
@echo off &setlocal
set currentDirectory="%CD%"
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /b /a-d *, The*.*') do (
set "fname=%%~a"
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set "nname=!fname:, The=!"
ren "!fname!" "!nname!"
endlocal
)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can use a Unix command shell, you could use the mv command in a loop.

You could download cygwin or Git Bash, or if you have Windows 10, you could do this right in the command line (assuming you've updated):

Creating a file like this

```
#!/bin/bash
for file in *.zip
do
    removedPart=", The"
    mv "${file}" "${file/removedPart/}"
done
```

You might want to test the command on a single file first to be sure it does what you want. i.e.

```
file=Test Title, The - Conspiracy.zip
removedPart=", The"
mv "${file}" "${file/removedPart/}"
```

Comment: This is assuming you want to rename the file, and not change text within the file. That made the most sense to me considering these are zip files.

Comment: Actually there are about 75 different extensions this for, but just figued I can use a wildacard to take care of them all.

Answer (score -1):

You can loop through the contents of the file directory in something like this loop.  [Batch script loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591758/batch-script-loop)

Then when you're looping through you can replace the contents of the file name.  Look at this: [String replacement in batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2772456/string-replacement-in-batch-file)

Sorry not more specific as Batch scripting isn't my thing.  But this logic should prove to at least be helpful.  Someone my post something better.

Comment: I think the OP wants to rename the file, not change text present in the file.

Comment: You are right.  The end file will have removed the ", The" from the middle of the filename and the add a"The" at the beginning.

Comment: Thanks for following up.  For not really working in Batch I think I would've resolved it. People are too critical on here sometimes, I just try to provide an answer where I can.