# How do I replace a substring in a string when both strings may contain reserved characters?

Tags: batch-file, replace

I'm having trouble figuring out a way to remove a substring from a string when both may have reserved characters in it. Nothing I've attempted has had any luck.

I'm new to batch, but right now I'm using the methods described here, with modifications: [String replacement in batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2772456/string-replacement-in-batch-file)

Here's my code sample, but it doesn't work at all with ! or : in the strings:

```
:: NOT WORKING
:RemoveWordsFromFileInLine

    :: %1 string to remove
    :: %2 source file
    :: %3 destination file

    setlocal enabledelayedexpansion    
    :: Loop through each "word" of every "line"
    set "toReplace=%1 "
    set "blank="

    del %3
    for /F "tokens=* delims=" %%a in (%2) do (    
    setlocal disabledelayedexpansion    
        echo "line=%%a"
        echo line is %line%

    setlocal enabledelayedexpansion    
        set "newLine=!line:%toReplace%=%blank%!"
        echo newLine is !newLine!
        @echo !newLine! >>%3
    endlocal    
    )

    if exist %3 ( move /y %3 %2 >nul )

GOTO:EOF
```

As you can see, I've tried disabling delayed expansion on the "set" of my line variable, but I can't do that in the replacement section itself.

Some example strings in the file are:

```
<!-- XML Comment goes here -->
<planets> Mars world:Earth </planets>
<planets> Venus Earth Mercury </planets>
```

Some example strings I'd look to replace are:

```
world:Earth
Earth
```

Anyone have any ideas on how I could make the string replacement work? I've tried numerous things, usually involving putting double quotes in various places (like around the line variable in the string replace statement), but I haven't had any luck yet.

Comment: `set "newLine=!%%a:%toReplace%=%blank%!"` --> `set "newLine=!line:%toReplace%=%blank%!"`

Comment: Sorry, yeah, that's how I used to have it. I had edited it in my attempts to fix and forgot to revert that portion. Thanks for catching that.

Comment: Actually, that helped it a bit... the early strings in the file (including the <!-- strings!!) are no longer breaking, which is a great step forward! but now most of the file is getting replaced with repeated !newLine! lines instead of their content will update my question once I figure out what I'm seeing exactly.

Comment: Interesting, looks like I hit "Maximum setlocal recursion level reached." in my log... so I guess that's an entirely different question.

Comment: Ah yes, you've got unbalanced `setlocal`/`endlocal` in your loop; I'd change the very first one (outside of the loop) to `setlocal DisableDelayedExsansion` and remove the second one (already in the loop), then it should be fine. Of course the line `echo line is %line%` in the loop can't work; it should be changed to `echo line is !line!` and moved below `setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion`...

Comment: Thanks for that - I ended up using a second endlocal as well just to keep them balanced completely. I just removed the echoes since they were only there for debugging - thanks so much for your help! I guess if you stare at something long enough you start missing obvious issues. Very glad to have had the extra eyes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So thanks to [aschipfl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5047996/aschipfl) for helping me figure this out; My main issues came down to poor usage of setlocal / endlocal. I'm pretty sure mucking this up is what's caused all my attempts to fail.

Final Code ended up:

```
:RemoveWordsFromFileInLine

    :: %1 string to remove
    :: %2 source file
    :: %3 destination file

    setlocal disabledelayedexpansion    
    :: Loop through each "word" of every "line"
    set "toReplace=%1 "
    set "blank="

    del %3
    for /F "tokens=* delims=" %%a in (%2) do (

        set "line=%%a"

    setlocal enabledelayedexpansion    
        set "newLine=!line:%toReplace%=%blank%!"
        @echo !newLine! >>%3
    endlocal    
    )
    endlocal    

    if exist %3 ( move /y %3 %2 >nul )

GOTO:EOF
```

Biggest things to note (as I understand them):

- Setting the line var requires disabledelayedexpansion, otherwise it will try to
  parse the ! in the line
- Setting enabledelayedexpansion to be on is required for the replace functionality 
  because we need to know what value of line is at that point of the loop.